# How to show UISearchToken in suggested searches list when user taps on searchbar?

Tags: uisearchbar, ios13, swift5, uisearchresultscontroller

[image]

Apple has announced new UIsearch bar api in WWDC 2019 : Modernizing Your UI for iOS 13. 
There we got to know new api for adding search tokens in search bar. but I wonder how we can achieve the representation of suggested searches as it's attached in screen shot. Please help

I tried this api in Xcode11.1

Comment: I am wondering the same, but I am afraid we need to populate our results table ourselves by listing all available tokens if the search text is empty.

Comment: The new searchable instance method in iOS16 may help you⟹ developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10052/?time=1392 

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by populating the tableview or collection-view, where you would show the results with your suggestions, or creating a new tableview / collection-view specifically for showing suggestions.

However UISearchToken is only in the search text field, so you would have to create a new UITableViewCell or UICollectionViewCell.